# Email, name, and custom properties in MailChimp (Swift 3)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, mailchimp

Here is my current knowledge on Mail Chimp. This is the code that creates the new email address:

```
let mailToSubscribe: [String: AnyObject] = ["email": "testing1234@gmail.com" as AnyObject]

let params: [String: AnyObject] = ["id": "ee08eac412" as AnyObject, "email": mailToSubscribe as AnyObject, "double_optin": false as AnyObject]

ChimpKit.shared().callApiMethod("lists/subscribe", withParams: params, andCompletionHandler: {(response, data, error) -> Void in
    if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {

        NSLog("Reponse status code: %d", httpResponse.statusCode)
        let datastring = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
        print(datastring!) // printing result of response
    }
})
```

I want to create the first and last name with the email. I've tried adding a dictionary value like this: ["name": "Test"] as! NSObject. What about other custom properties as well, such as phone number, address etc.?

[image: Problem 1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let mailToSubscribe: [String: AnyObject] = ["email": "testing1234@gmail.com", "merge_vars" : [ "FNAME" : "Test" , "LNAME" : "Test"]]
```

Comment: Nice, why is it merge_vars? What if I were to create a new field, would `merge_vars` change?

Comment: I guess that's how Mailchimp likes it.

https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582487-How-to-Use-Merge-Tags-to-Add-Dynamic-Content

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `MERGE TAGS` in mailchimp and then you set dictionary objects to those keys accordingly e.g. `FIRST_NAME`, `LAST_NAME`, `BIRTHDAY` etc.